# How to prevent going back to previous page on Flutter Web via browser back button?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, router

After a user successfully logged in in my Flutter web app, it should be taken to a dashboard view.

The user then should not be able to navigate back to the login screen by pressing the browser back button.

I tried a lot of things, replacing the route, popping the route and then pushing the next route, all did not work.

Also using `WillPopScope` in the dashboard page does not work. Pressing the browser back button does not fire `onWillPop`.

Found some similar questions, but they all end up suggesting `WillPopScope` or replacing the route, both did not work for me.

Any idea what I could do?

Comment: You may implemented your WillPopScope wrong, look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can't intercept the browser back buttons.

I solved the problem by using a RouteGuard of the auto_route package which intercepts the navigation and checks if the user is authenticated or not. If the user is already authenticated, the navigation to the Signin page is canceled.

Check the auto_route package for examples and further explanation: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#route-guards

Answer (score -1):

Wrap it inside a WillPopScope and return false

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => Future.value(false),
      child: DashboardView(),
      ),
```

Comment: As I said, this does not work with the browser back buttons in flutter web. Onwillpop does not fire. I tried it the exact same way.